# C++ errors in code

Tags: c++

I have this code (question from exam) and there are many errors in the code, here is the code:

```
 class A
 {
   int z;
   static int y;
   public:
     A() {(*this).incrementY();}
    int x () { y=y+2; return z;}
    static int getY(){ return z;}
    void incrementY() {y++}
 };
 class B: A
 {
   public:
    B (): A() {(*this).incrementY();};
 };
 class C : public B
 {
   public:
    C(): B() {(*this).incrementY;() }
 };

 int main()
 {
   A::x();
   A a;
   a.getY();
   A::getY();
   B b;
   C c;
   C::getY();
   b.x();
 }
```

There is a private inheritance. This means that all the methods and variables in B become private to any class that inherits from B?

Comment: This code is terrible, but it's best that you check it with any free C++ compiler. You'll get the whole story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct there (although it actually means that all *A*'s methods become inaccessible).

However, there are a few other problems:

```
A::x() // will not work as x is not static.
a.getY() // will not work as getY() is static.
C::getY() // Cannot access getY()
```

Answer (score 3):

There are so many that you cannot but get tired. Here are some:

```
void incrementY() {y++}
```

No `;` after `y++`.

```
24.   A::x();
```

Non static member cannot be invoked via a class name.

```
25.   A a;
```

No definition of static member `y`. If `y` was a `const` this would've been okay. This is a bit tricky so I'll quote.

> **9.4.2 Static data members**
>
> 2. The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified void [...]
> 3. If a static data member is of const effective literal type, its declaration in the class definition can specify
>      a constant-initializer brace-or-equal-initializer with an initializer-clause that is an integral constant expression.
>      A static data member of effective literal type can be declared in the class definition with the
>      constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a constant-initializer brace-or-equal-initializer with an initializer-clause that is an integral constant expression. In both these cases, the member may appear in integral constant expressions. The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is used in the program and the  namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.

```
26.   a.getY();
27.   A::getY();
```

Illegal reference to non-static member `A::z`.

Taken care of by first observation.

```
28.   B b;
29.   C c;
30.   C::getY();
```

`getY()` is a private member of `B`, not visible to `C`, let alone be public.

```
31.   b.x();
```

The member function `x()` inherited from `A` is private.

Comment: I voted you up. But please note that the quote is from the working paper of the next Standard. So it mentions things not appearing in current C++ in effect (literal types, constexpr).

Comment: @litb: I usually mention that (n2798, C++0x draft). Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct, although you could just compile it with any number of online C++ compilers to verify.